# PHPUnit: mock non-existing classes

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

**Is it possible to create a mock of non-existing class in PHPUnit?**
Let's assume I have some class that creates instance of another class, for example:

```php
class TaskRunner
{
    public function runTasks()
    {
        // Run through some loop to get tasks and store each in $taskName
        // Get task instance by given task name 
        $task = $this->getTaskInstance($taskName);
        if ($task instanceof AbstractTask) {
            $task->run();
        }
    }

    protected function getTaskInstance($taskName)
    {
        // Just an example
        return new $taskName();
    }
}
```

I would like to run unit test for `runTasks` method to check if created task instace extends some abstract class.
**Is there any possibility to NOT to create sample class in a filesystem to check the inheritance constraint?**
Thanks for all!

Comment: `->getMock('AbstractTask')`?

Comment: @PeeHaa Ok, that's ok for getting the condition to run true. What about non `AbstracTask`-extending classes? Mock `stdClass`?

Comment: You can mock concrete classes as well with phpunit. But more likely you want to typehint an interface instead.

Comment: @PeeHaa Of course, I get what you mean. But let's assume there are two classes, one extends `AbstractClass` and the second, which extends nothing, pure base class. I don't want to create them in filesystem but I do want to mock them. The first, ok I can mock `AbstractClass`, it does the job. What about the second one? It doesn't implement any interface, nor extends any other class. And I want to write a test for `instanceof` condition failing.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to stub/mock classes that do not exist with PHPUnit. Simply do

```php
 $this->getMockBuilder('NameOfClass')->setMethods(array('foo'))->getMock();
```

to create an object of non-existant class `NameOfClass` that provides one method, `foo()`, that can be configured using the API as usual.

Since **PHPUnit 9**, you shall replace :

- `'NameOfClass'` by `\stdClass::class`
- `setMethods` by `addMethods`

```php
$this->getMockBuilder(\stdclass::class)->addMethods(array('foo'))->getMock();
```

Comment: Great! So the class doesn't have to exists physically in a file system to mock it? Won't PHPUnit throw any excetpion?

Comment: No, PHPUnit won't throw an exception. Why don't you just go ahead and try it instead of asking?

Comment: I answered by phone, I wasn't able to test it by myself in that moment :) Sorry.

Comment: @SebastianBergmann, this code won't work for PHPUnit 10 due to deprecation of `setMethods()` in v9. Is it possible to create mock for not existed class in modern PHPUnit mock API?

Comment: @rodion.arr now you can use the method `addMethods`. See the https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/3687

Comment: @rodion.arr I edited the answer to add the new method addMethods and to replace the dummy name by the smallest existent class: stdClass.

Comment: `addMethods()` is also now deprecated in PHPUnit 10.1 and will be removed in PHPUnit 12. https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/5320

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is perfect, except that since **PHPUnit 9** there is an issue, if you need to mock a class that is required to be of a certain instance. In that case `\stdclass::class` cannot be used.

And using

```php
$this->getMockBuilder('UnexistentClass')->addMethods(['foo'])->getMock();
```

will result in `Class UnexistentClass does not exist`, because `addMethod` checks the given methods against the given class methods.

In case anybody else is having the same issue, luckly `setMethods` still works, so this still works in PHPUnit 9

```php
$this->getMockBuilder('UnexistentClass')->setMethods(['foo'])->getMock();
```

*Note though that `setMethods` will be removed in **PHPUnit 10***

Hopefully at that time there will be a fix for this issue. Like for example checking if `allowMockingUnknownTypes` is set to `true`. If that check is implemented this will then work too:

```php
$this->getMockBuilder('UnexistentClass')->allowMockingUnknownTypes()
->addMethods(['foo'])->getMock();
```

Comment: `$this->mock = $this->getMockBuilder('Domain\Customer\Models\Customer')->setMethods(['foo'])->getMock();`

I use PHPUnit 9.5.10, and I get this error:
`Error: Call to undefined method Domain\Customer\Models\Customer::getConnectionName()`

Any ideas?

Comment: that is likely because you set as methods 'foo', but somewhere getConnectionName is called. Therefore you'd need to setMethods(['getConnectionName']) and all other methods that will eventually be used