# Use User model in a Lumen package

Tags: laravel, testing, lumen

I wrote a Lumen package that make a reference to User Model.

I can't use `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` because it doesn't exists with Lumen 5.7

I've made a config file that I publish, which give a reference to the User model that exists in the app. In this case:

my-config-plugin.php

```
'user' => [
        'table'       => 'users',
        'primary_key' => 'id',
        'foreign_key' => 'user_id',
        'model'       => App\User::class,
    ],
```

so, in all my package, I use:

config('my-config-plugin.user.model') and it resolves to `App\User::class`

But my problem comes with my tests, because there is no `App\User::class` defined in my package, so all the tests fail.

So, the only solution I find is to define my tests in another Lumen project that will have a User model and will install the plugin, but I don't like very much to ave my tests in another repository. Am I missing the good way to do it?

Comment: Would mocking this class be an option for you?

Comment: Maybe, but I am afraid not to understand well, mocking is to replace existing class, so if the class doesn't exists, I don't know how to do it

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125444/phpunit-mock-non-existing-classes it explains how you can create a fake representation of a non existing class by defining the methods on it, and after that using the normal mock workflow to let these methods always return the value you want for testing